# Exporting an `org` file to a personal LaTeX class

Tags: org-mode, org-export, init-file

I have a personal LaTeX class called `MyThesis`, and I want to be able of exporting from `org` to `LaTeX`.

**Q:** How can I call this class that is not in the main tree of `texlive`?

I have this in my `.emacs`

```
(use-package org
  :defer t
  :config
  (use-package ox-latex
    :defer 5
    :config
    (add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
         '("MyThesis"
           "\\documentclass{MyThesis}"
           ("\\part{%s}" . "\\part*{%s}")
           ("\\chapter{%s}" . "\\chapter*{%s}")
           ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
           ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
           ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}"))
         )
    )
  )
```

but I don't know how to tell it where if the file! (Shame on me!)

Comment: The easiest solution may be to install your personal class in a way that Texlive can see it. This has been [answered elsewhere on stackexchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1137/where-do-i-place-my-own-sty-or-cls-files-to-make-them-available-to-all-my-te). If that doesn't do what you need, perhaps you can clarify exactly what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Follow @tyler's advice first for finding locations in your TeX installation, but for the syntax for using use-package in your init.el, use this pared down example below. Note defer is implied.

```
(use-package org
 :config
    (add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
        '("MyThesis"
               "\\documentclass{MyThesis}"
               ("\\part{%s}" . "\\part*{%s}")
               ("\\chapter{%s}" . "\\chapter*{%s}")
               ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
               ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
               ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}"))))
```